# make spacial plots in python using available modules

Tags: colorbar

I want to plot the spacial plot of different land use land categories data as wrf model output.  Initially i tried by using the available colorcodes in the python module matplotlib.colors but, i unable to set the color bar with diffrent colors for each different category. kindly suggest the available modules in python to rectify this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you share some more details about what you've tried so far? Maybe some code snippets?